# How to change change Kafka retention which is not working

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using dockerised wurstmeister/kafka-docker. I created a topic using

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 27 --topic raw-sensor-data --config retention.ms=86400000
```

After a few days I tried changing retention period by

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name raw-sensor-data --add-config retention.ms=3600000
```

I also tried

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper locahost:2181 --alter --topic raw-sensor-data --config retention.ms=3600000
```

and

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic raw-sensor-data --config cleanup.policy=delete
```

This also gets reflected in topic describe details

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides

Topic: raw-sensor-data  PartitionCount: 27      ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=delete,retention.ms=3600000
```

But I can still see old data and data is not getting deleted in 1 hour time.

In server.properties I have

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

Answer (score 0):

Only closed log segments will be deleted. The default segment size is 1GB.

So, if you have less data in the topic, it will remain, regardless of the time that has passed.